# Invalid Hook Call Warning on using react-hook-form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

im new to react and trying to run the below code, but get the error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Ive tried to follow the steps below to help identify whats gone wrong but have not been able to fix it. ( I dont believe the issue is with points 2, or 3.)
https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
  console.log(errors);
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input type="text" placeholder="First name" {...register("First name", {required: true, maxLength: 80})} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" {...register("Last name", {required: true, maxLength: 100})} />
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" {...register("Email", {required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i})} />
      <input type="tel" placeholder="Mobile number" {...register("Mobile number", {required: true, minLength: 6, maxLength: 12})} />

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

According to the items in my node_module folder, the version of both react, and react-dom are 17.0.2.

Is there something ive done wrong?

Many thanks

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code into a sandbox and it runs fine. So there might be nothing wrong with the snippet of code you are sharing. Did you check for multiple react versions `npm ls react`? Could there be some other portion of your code not represented where you may be calling a hook from an invalid location?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this one, I was not able to fix the issue but ive just created myself another project and copied the above code in, works as expected now. I have no idea what the issue was with my previous project.

Comment: That is strange but great to hear also. All the best with the project!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your ran `npm install --save react-hook-form` (or similar for `yarn`) in the wrong directory, and therefore your actual `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files do not contain a reference to the `react-hook-form` package. If so, your `import` statement might have setup an invalid reference to  `useForm`.